# Get data from mysql between two timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I am trying to get the data out of my database by searching between two timestamps.  Below is my query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE time BETWEEN '1362355200' AND '1362959999'")
```

When the query runs I do not get any errors or results.

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [_prepared statements_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Comment: Please don't use `BETWEEN` for date/time/timestamp values.  Really, it's thinking about things the wrong way.  [This article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) details some SQL Server-specific problems, but the concepts still apply.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and links, appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`time` is a reserved keyword. Try putting it in ticks:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE `time` BETWEEN '1362355200' AND '1362959999'
```

Comment: also to remember is BETWEEN does not INCLUDE the inputted time stamps so in your case it would be 1362355201 1362959998 if you want to include your actual time stamps then you'll want to do where `time`>= AND `time`<=.  BETWEEN is the same as < > not <= >=

Comment: It does if you dont put it between quotes. The comparisment used in between is `>=` and `<=`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: I tried this  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE where time>='1362355200' AND time<='1362959999'")  but i get the following error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where 'time'>='1362355200' AND 'time'<='1362959999'' at line 1

Comment: You have a double WHERE

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the qoutes around the values. If you want to compare numeric values, dont use them. Check [the manual on BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) for more information

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE `time` BETWEEN 1362355200 AND 1362959999
```

Comment: Thanks when i run the above in PhpMyAdmin it comes back error,  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table WHERE `time` BETWEEN 1362355200 AND 1362959999' at line 2